# Schrödinger Wave Function times its spatial derivative equals zero?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

We had an exam question for calculating the expected value of momentum for a 1D box. Within the integral teacher just wrote zero for $\psi \frac{d\psi}{dx}$. Is this a general thing or just for a stationary particle in a box situation, and if so how?

Answer (score 2):

For real square integrable functions,
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi(x) \partial_x \psi(x)\, dx =\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \partial_x \psi(x)^2\, dx=\left.\frac{1}{2}\psi(x)^{2}\right|_{-\infty}^{\infty}=0$$

For bound states. the eigenvalue equation is real and the eigenfunctions can be chosen to be real valued, yielding the expectation zero for any  component momentum operator. This is, natural, of course, for a bound system, classically as a time average.

Motion needs complex state vectors with non-constant phase $e^{i f(t,x)}$. The transport current form is the imaginary part of
$$\Im\left(\psi^* \nabla \psi\right)  =\frac{1}{2i} \ \left(\psi^* \nabla \psi-\psi \nabla \psi^* \right).$$